# Can't post on my wall using restFB

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

When i try to post on wall, I got this error

Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to     perform this action

This is my code

```
   String API_KEY = "My key";
   String SECRET = "my secret";
   AccessToken token=(new DefaultFacebookClient().obtainAppAccessToken(API_KEY, SECRET));
// System.out.println(token.getAccessToken());

 FacebookClient fb=new DefaultFacebookClient(token.getAccessToken());
 FacebookType publishMessageResponse= fb.publish("me/feed", FacebookType.class,
         Parameter.with("message", "Try to post"));
```

In my application, I have permission to publish_action and publish_stream.
Any idea how fix this?

Comment: any one know the answer??

Answer (score 0):

You can use facbook4j jar file for posting on your facebook wall.
If you wan to use it then use below code for the post the wall.

```
Facebook facebook = new FacebookFactory().getInstance();
String appId = "APP_ID";
String appSecret = "APP_SEC";
facebook.setOAuthAppId(appId, appSecret);
String commaSeparetedPermissions ="user_friends,user_groups,user_photos,user_videos,user_birthday,user_status,user_likes,user_activities,user_location";
facebook.setOAuthPermissions(commaSeparetedPermissions);
String accessToken = "ACCESS_TOCKEN";
facebook.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken(accessToken, null));
facebook.postStatusMessage("Hello World from Facebook4J From Java Programming....");
```

Above code you have to add APP_ID, APP_SEC, and ACCESS_TOCKEN from your facebook application

THis below link you can get the help for other coding

http://facebook4j.org/en/code-examples.html